# Pyspark only runs using sudo

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get pyspark to run in terminal on Mac OS X; when I run it without sudo, I get the following message:

[image]

However, if i type 'sudo pyspark' this happens

[image].

Is there a way I can type 'pyspark' into terminal without it asking me for my password i.e. having to write sudo first? Thanks

Comment: You can just give your user sudo permissions: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76088/how-do-i-give-a-user-sudo-permissions

Comment: How did you install `pyspark`? What's the directory where you start `pyspark`? The reason is that you don't have access to metastore that is automatically created when you start `pyspark`.

Comment: @mtoto I already have sudo, otherwise it wouldn't load when I type sudo pyspark into terminal, no? do you mean I should change permissions on the folder it is sitting in?

Comment: I check `which pyspark` and it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec//bin/pyspark` (goodness knows why!)

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered this problem.The machine is mac and I install pyspark by brew. In my situation, the problem is caused by the ~/.bash_profile. The problematic spark export statement is as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0  
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME
```

In this situation, pyspark only runs using sudo.
After I modify spark export statement as follows,

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.0/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME
```

I can run pyspark by command 'pyspark'.